# How to assign an order for TreeSet in Scala without repeating myself

Tags: scala, scala-collections, treeset, sortedset

I have this segment of Scala code which defines an ordering and applies it to a TreeSet.  This part compiles fine.

```
val acctOrdering = new Ordering[Account] {
  def compare(acc1: Account, acc2: Account) {

    // code to compare based on various criteria

  }
}

private var accountSet = new TreeSet[Account]()(acctOrdering)
```

Elsewhere in the code, I want to get the first element in the set (and later on get subsequent ones if the first one doesn't produce what I want, although that usually won't be necessary), based on the order I previously specified.  I thought the following would work, but it didn't compile:

```
val firstAccount = accountSet.min
```

The error is `"could not find implicit value for parameter cmp: Ordering[Account]"`

However, if I specify the ordering object again when asking for the minimum, it compiles:

```
val firstAccount = accountSet.min(acctOrdering)
```

I thought it would have automatically used the ordering I gave at construction time, and incrementally sorting as I added to the set, so I wouldn't have to specify the ordering again when calling `min`.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to explicitly define an implicit function somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is happening is that you are assuming `min` depends on the ordering of the set, but it doesn't. Specifically, `min` and `max` are generic methods available on pretty much any collection, and they take an implicit `Ordering` parameter.

However, if you try `firstKey` and `lastKey`, which are `SortedSet`-specific methods, they'll work without having to pass any implicit.

**Edit**

One question you might have posed is to how do you make sure your `Account` type can be ordered by any method expecting an `Ordering`. You can do that by putting an implicit definition inside `Account`'s object companion, like this:

```
object Account {
  implicit val ord = new Ordering[Account] {
    def compare(ac1: Account, acc2: Account): Int = {
      // code to compare based on various criteria
    }
  }
}
```

Once you do that, you won't need to pass the ordering explicitly.

Comment: Thanks.  Changing `min` to `firstKey` gets it to compile.

There two versions of min, one without a parameter and another with an implicit.  Just for my understanding of it, how would the method  `def  min  : A` be used?

Comment: OK, now I think I get it ... it appears the parameterless `min` is never usable on TreeSet, because calling it without a parameter will always revert to the version of min that expects an implicit parameter.

Comment: @Gigatron There's only one `min` definition. The other definition you see on ScalaDoc is marked as "_use case_". That means this is not a real signature, but a "fake" signature that represents what happens most of the time. In this case, calling `min` without any parameter will work most of the time.

Comment: @Gigatron However, I see now that I could have been more helpful in my answer, so see the edit for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, especially about "use case".  In this situation the particular ordering is for a very specific purpose that isn't useful to the rest of the application, so I won't put the ordering in Account itself.

Comment: what's the return type of compare()? In Java compareTo returns a boolean.

Comment: @Adrian The same as in Java: an `Int`, not a `Boolean` as you claimed. Note that `Ordering` is equivalent to Java's `Comparator`, not `Comparable`, and `Comparable`'s `compare` method _also_ returns an `Int`. And both JavaDoc and ScalaDoc document the exact meaning of the `Int` returned.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral ah you're right! It's an int.. I must've been really tired. My confusion was bc I didn't see a return type on the compare method; I assumed it was Unit... which didn't make sense.

Comment: @Adrian Well, leaving the return type out on a public method is bad form, so I fixed that now.